# Chrome is again with images

Tags: image, http, client

At the footer you may see buttons for social media in grey. Problem is i wasnt seeing them when i uploaded the files to the server and going to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try again after pausing the adblock plugin.

Comment: may look this question about the same http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223764/what-are-these-errors-about-in-the-chrome-console-when-visiting-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

this could happen because you use some Chrome extension/plugin that blocks the images.
Plus, seems you have a javascript syntax exception there.